# Exit on network or other failure when recording an RTSP stream

Tags: ffmpeg, timeout, rtsp

I am using ffmpeg on linux to record an rtsp stream from a cctv dvr. Sometimes the recording silently stops and ffmpeg just continues to run, and the only way I can detect this is that the output file size is not increasing, and if a progress file is specified, that stops being written too.

I can recreate the situation by dropping the route to the dvr from the PC running ffmpeg.

I've read about several ways to set a timeout but none of them seem to have the desired effect - as an example the most apparently promising 'stimeout' is just totally ignored for rtsp, in my experience, and I've seen it written that this is not for use with rtsp.

So I am wondering if anyone else has found an option which can set the desired behaviour when recording rtsp - ideally I would like it to exit if no data is received for n seconds. I've been messing round with various methods to detect it externally (like monitoring the increase in file size) but its not 100% reliable and fast to detect the problem under all conditions - it would be far better to get ffmpeg to indicate the loss of data itself if possible.

Comment: Have you tried something simple like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002614/is-it-possible-to-do-a-simple-health-check-of-rtsp-stream-with-curl-tool I haven't tested it but it looks promising.

Comment: @Gantendo that question is interesting but it dosen't really seem to fit my issue. In my case the dvr 'fixes' itself - restarting ffmpeg gets everything going again. But its a matter of detecting when the fault happens. Theres 2 streams being recorded a slow and fast, and at night the slow stream is filling up the output file so slowly that 10 minutes can go by with no writes. So if I watch the file it means at least 10 minutes of lost recording. Although I could query the dvr every few minutes I would likely not catch it failing because it comes back up quickly - but ffmpeg has by then hung.